# How to convert units of various types then average the results

Tags: sql, mysql, average

I have a table that has various torque values in units of imperial and metric.
I would like to convert the metric values into imperial and then average all values as a total average with the imperial result.
How do I convert each row into the same unit and then run the average in one query?
The units are sent as a string.

I am using MySql

to convert NM to FtLbs

```
Imperial = NMtorque x 0.73756
```

The result should be from all rows of average Torque in imperial units

```
SELECT avg(torque) as avg from TorqueTestResults

ID  TORQUE UNITS
===================
1   100       Lb.ft
2   120       Lb.ft
3   135       N.m
4   140       N.m
```

Comment: A [mcve] is expected to include _both_ sample table data _and_ the expected result.

Comment: Just use your multiplier conditionally - `SELECT AVG(IF(UNITS = 'N.m', TORQUE * 0.73756, TORQUE)) AS avg FROM TorqueTestResults`

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure using IF would take each row individually and THEN average